# How do I update the corresponding input when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you help me to how to update the input field when the button is clicked. When the add button is clicked it needs to update the text in the input field next to it

```
                        <div class="columns small-6">
                            <p><?php echo $product_one_name; ?></p> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="columns small-6 ">
                            <button class="addButton"> + </button>
                            <input class="products-quantity" type="text" name="product_one_name" value="" placeholder="quantity">
                            <button class="subButton"> - </button>
                        </div>
                        <hr>



                        <div class="columns small-6">
                            <p><?php echo $product_two_name; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="columns small-6 ">
                            <button class="addButton"> + </button>
                            <input class="products-quantity" type="text" name="product_two_name" value="" placeholder="quantity">
                            <button class="subButton"> - </button>
                        </div>
                        <hr>



priceCalculation: function(){
                var addButton = document.getElementsByClassName('addButton');

                var i = 0;
                $(addButton).on('click', function(e){  
                    e.preventDefault();
                    i++;
                    var inputValue = $(this).parent().children()[1].value;

                    var newQuantity = inputValue + i;

                    console.log(newQuantity);


                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find closest input with class .products-quantity using jQuery and update its value.

```
        $(addButton).on('click', function(e){  
            e.preventDefault();
            var button = $(e.target);
            var input = button.closest('.columns').find('input.products-quantity');
            var currentVal = parseInt(input.val() || 0);
            input.val(++currentVal);
        });
```

Comment: Stefan, It worked perfectly. Tank you very much :). Really appreciate it.